# If all $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise, does $f \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

Tags: limits, analysis, sequence-of-function

It sounds like it should be a standard result but I can't find a statement or proof of it. Does anyone have a reference or counterexample? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is true.
$$f_n(x) = \min\{1,\max\{0,n-x^2\}\}$$
should be a counterexample